# echo selected SQL row data using PHP

Tags: php

If I collect multiple row data from SQL, I will have to use foreach loop or something else to display that data properly.
How to use these PHP strings without using foreach loop ?

Following is my SQL query

```
$results = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM specs where id in ('.$id1.','.$id2.','.$id3.','.$id4.') ');
```

It will result data from 4 different rows.

The above code is just an example, below is the exact code I am using in my page.

```
try{
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databse", "user", "password");
    // Set the PDO error mode to exception
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Attempt select query execution
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM specs WHERE id IN($id1,$id2,$id3,$id4)";
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
    $results = $result->fetchAll();

} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
 
// Close connection
unset($pdo);
```

Currently, the data is displayed using the following

```
<tr>
<td>Brand</td>
<?php foreach ($results as $result){ ?>
    <td> <strong><?php echo $result['brand']; ?></strong> </td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
```

There will be total 4 results, I wan to use that 4 results separately.
If the results are
Samsung, Sony, Apple, LG - how can I echo the "Apple" only using PHP string ?

Comment: You cannot, if you have  result set you need to iterate it, that's programming.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @biesior, You mean there is no way to select the first or second data alone ? like echo $brand[0];

Comment: return it as array so you'll be able to get it by index, That are PHP basics, sorry I won't paste samples for that.

Comment: @Dharman , thank you for the warning, this was only my test code, not the original code.

Comment: Can you show us a proper example without such bugs instead?

Comment: @Dharman, in the question, I have added the original SQL code.

Comment: It's still broken. You are mixing PDO and MySQLi. You need to parameterize the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch all the rows.  If you have the *MySQL Native Driver*:

```
$rows = $results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Otherwise, fetch with a loop:

```
while($rows[] = $results->fetch_assoc());
```

Then you can access them by row:

```
echo $rows[0]['brand'];  // first row

echo $rows[1]['brand'];  // second row
```

But that's not very useful.  If you have something unique that you want to use (I use `brand` as an example though it's probably not), then just index on that:

```
$rows = array_column($results->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC), null, 'brand');
// or
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { $rows[$row['brand']] = $row; }
// then
echo $rows['apple']['model'];
```